# Programatically update product price in Magento - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to programatically update a product's price within a custom module. This is my code:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); // for debug only
try
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $product->setPrice($newPrice);
    $product->save();
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo "Error: ". $ex->getMessage();
}
```

When this code executes, I get the following exception:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1180

In the `system.log` file, I see allot of these entries:

> 2016-03-17T18:01:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied
>   for foreach()  in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1180 2016-03-17T18:01:06+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error:
>   Argument 3 passed to
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute() must be of
>   the type array, null given, called in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1225 and defined  in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php
>   on line 543 2016-03-17T18:01:06+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error:
>   Argument 3 passed to
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute() must be of the
>   type array, null given, called in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php
>   on line 545 and defined  in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1254 2016-03-17T18:01:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1256

Any idea what might be causing this? The same code on my dev magento setup works, but in production magento, this error started to appear, so I am a little confused.

Comment: `must be of type array, null given`... so there you go. you passed a null to something expecting an array instead.

Comment: @MarcB already check `$newPrice` it's not null and not meant to be an array either. I am perplexed by the error, because it's so random.

Answer (score 26):

You can to try set the store:

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

Comment: Why? My code is executing within a custom module, which is already in the adminhtml with the necessary permissions. I will try noneless.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have to do this now in the current version of Magento. Maybe someone else can explain?

Comment: This fixed my issue too.  Running a standalone script from the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

```
$storeId='store_id';

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$productIds = array('products_ids');

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addStoreFilter();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
foreach($products as $product)
{
    $price=$product->setPrice('price');
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
    $product->save(); 
}
```

Try this code, It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. Need to pass store Id. This seems to be the issue.

```
$array_product = array($productId);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($array_product, array('price' => $newPrice), $storeId);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please make a note if you update product programmatically then try to avoid magento save function which is perfect for single product but when you will use lots of product it will make your site slow. Please use my below code then rendex magento over SSH . it will work fine for you.

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');


$write->query("
                      UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal val
                      SET  val.value = (".$productPrice['Price'].")
                      WHERE  val.attribute_id = (
                         SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute eav
                         WHERE eav.entity_type_id = 4 
                           AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
                        )
                        AND val.entity_id = '".$product->getId()."'
                    ");
```

Comment: This work but you must to run reindex routine to update flat table and catalog_product_index_price table.

Comment: You can pro grammatically reindex by using this code  . $process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexAll();